# Jenkins not applying credentials for git

Tags: java, git, jenkins, raspberry-pi

I'm running Jenkins 2.89.2 in Java on Raspberry Pi 3.

I have a git repository located at */srv/git/repo.git*, and a user "git" with full access to this directory. I'm creating a pipeline that should check out the repository, configured like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YEyz.png) with correct git credentials.

Whenever I try to run a job, Jenkins times out [at this point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPl8X.png). When I check the console where Jenkins is running, Jenkins is idle and waiting for me to type in "git@localhost's password". Why is it asking me for the password when I already gave the credentials? I also tried adding "git@localhost" as the username for the credentials.

Any ideas? When I *do* enter the password into the console, the job proceeds and succeeds.

Comment: Have you tried authenticating with SSH keys?

Comment: SSH had the same problem: received prompt to enter password in console at the `git ls-remote --symref git@localhost:/srv/git/repo.git` step.

Comment: Ended up just setting repository path to the local _/srv/git/repo.git_. That's a bad solution, since it forces me to run Jenkins on the same machine as the repository. But I was probably going to do that anyway! This issue has just drained too many hours.